# How to create,store and access fileopen picker 's Image in local storage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working with windows phone 8.1 album application , I want to store more than 100 Image in album but file open picker can't handle more than 5-6 Images 
Is this possible to access image using path or set image source as phone storage ?
which is the best way to store image in database image, taken by file open picker

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `FileOpenPicker`, you can directly access the phone libraries using `KnownFolders`. This, however, requires you to declare capability in application manifest.
Assuming you are interested in pictures only, you can add capability for `Pictures Library` in manifest. Then access the pictures library in your code as

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
```

Now you can use `picturesFolder` to access the images library files and folders.

Comment: Thank you abhishek ,                                                                                  i am working with chat application with image sharing i have to add that image in my List View which is pick from file open picker and store to data base , but the problem is sqlite can not store bitamap image and my application can't handle more image only 4-5 images (1mb per image ) what should i do ? please help